# update lines in a file

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a file,where it has some fields.For example,

```
var One = "fcb";
var Two = "abc";
```

How can I **update/replace** these lines using a script?

I want to be able to do something like :

```
   echo -n "Enter One: "
   read  One
   echo -n "Enter Two: "
   read  Two

   sed -i $One ./file.js
   sed -i $Two ./file.js
```

But, when I execute the script:

```
Enter One: fge3
Enter Two: ghj5
```

it shows:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `f'
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, it sounds/looks like you want to replace "fcb" in file.js with "fge3". Is that right?

Comment: @ZacharyBrady:Yes,that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed command would look something like

```
sed -i -e 's/var One =.*/var One = "'$One'";/' -e 's/var Two =.*/var Two = "'$Two'";/' file.js
```

Edit to add:

Beware of a gotcha... if the user enters nasty characters like `foo/bar` as the answer :-)

2nd Edit:

If you don't want to *allow* the bad character then you can abort
eg after the `read One` you can add:

```
if [[ "$One" =~ "/" ]]; then echo bad char / not allowed; exit; fi
```

You could pick a different character instead for the `sed` statement (e.g. a `|` instead of `/`) and disallow that.

Otherwise you'll need to try some clever quoting...

```
One=$(echo "$One" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
```

Comment: :Ok , it works great!Thanks!What about the gotcha?How can you avoid them?

Comment: Answer edited to try and deal with the gotcha.